# Как исправить отправку на почту?

Tags: javascript, express

```
if(!req.body.mail || !req.body.adres) return res.sendStatus(400)
const message = {
    to: '<test@gmail.com>',
    subject: 'Заказ',
    text:`Заказ 
    данные:
    почта: ${req.body.mail}
    адрес: ${req.body.adres}
    продукт: ${req.body.element_name}`
}
```

И есть такой код

```
 if (productsStore.indexOf(id) !== -1) {
            htmlCatalog += `
                <tr>
                    <td class="shopping_element_name"  name="element_name">${name}</td>
                    <td class="shopping_element_price">${price} ₽</td>
                </tr>
            `;
                 sumCatalog += price;
        }
const html = `
    <div class="shopping_cart">
        <div class="shoppingClose" onclick="shoppingPage.handleCartHide();">
            <span class="hideCartjs"></span>
            <span class="hideCartjsTwo"></span>
            <span class="hideCartNoneJs"></span>
        </div>
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:3001/gareg">
        <table>
            ${htmlCatalog}
                <tr>
                    <td class="shopping_element_name">Полная сумма:</td>
                    <td class="shopping_element_price" name="allprice">${sumCatalog} ₽</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        <input class="mailClient" name="mail" type="mail" placeholder="Введите свою почту..." 
required/>
        <input class="adress" name="adres" placeholder="Введите адрес доставки..." required/>
        <div>
            <button class="buyProduct" type="submit">Оформить</button>
        </div>
    </form>    
    </div>
    `;
```

Не могу понять, как отправить `${name}` продукта на почту.

На почте выдаёт: продукт: undefined.

Comment: Где инициализируется и в каком месте кода переменная name получает значение?

Comment: name находится в файле catalog.json, а можно как-то сделать <td name="elName" ></td>?

Comment: Rudi в catalog.json находятся только карточки с товарами

Comment: `<form>...<input type="hidden" name="element_name" value="__тут_что_то__">...</form>`